# iOS:How to dismiss other UIViewcontroller in current UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have three modal `UIViewController` "A","B" and "C". "A" and "C" is `Portrait` , "B" is "LandscapeRight" I click the button in "A" , "B" `UIViewController` will present , If I click the button in "B" , "C" `UIViewController` will present , When I click the button in "C"  , I want to let "B" `UIViewController` dismiss before "C" `UIViewController` dismiss

I have try to put "B" `UIViewController` to "C" and dismiss the "B" when click the button

in "B"

```
let c = UIViewController()
c.b = self
self.presentViewController(c, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

then I click the button in "C"

```
b.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

    })
})
```

When "C" is dismiss , "B" still display in the screen and did not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to dismiss a view controller before the view controller present from it is disappeared.
As an alternative,you can try this way,add a bool variable in the B,and change the variable in the C.

code in B:

```
var shouldShow:Bool = true

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if !shouldShow{
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in
            //
        }
    }
}
```

code in C:

```
@IBAction func clickButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    vc!.shouldShow = false
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        //
    })
}
```